# How does modulus of a smaller dividend and larger divisor work?

Tags: c, math

```
7 % 3 = 1 (remainder 1)
```

how does
`3 % 7`   (remainder ?)

work?

Comment: Just an FYI - your computer's calculator can do modulus.

Comment: @John B: yeah but I can't. yet...

Comment: @John B: yeah but I can't. yet... –best comment ever

Answer (score 49, accepted):

remainder of 3/7 is 3..since it went 0 times with 3 remainder so 3%7 = 3

Answer (score 9):

7 goes into 3?  zero times with 3 left over.

quotient is zero.  Remainder (modulus) is 3.

Answer (score 9):

Conceptually, I think of it this way. By definition, your dividend must be equal to `(quotient * divisor) + modulus`

Or, solving for modulus: `modulus = dividend - (quotient * divisor)`

Whenever the dividend is less than the divisor, the quotient is always zero which results in the modulus simply being equal to the dividend.

To illustrate with OP's values:

```
modulus of 3 and 7 = 3 - (0 * 7) = 3
```

To illustrate with other values:

```
1 % 3:
1 - (0 * 3) = 1

2 % 3:
2 - (0 * 3) = 2
```

Answer (score 7):

The same way.  The quotient is 0 (3 / 7 with fractional part discarded).  The remainder then satisfies:

```
(a / b) * b + (a % b) = a
(3 / 7) * 7 + (3 % 7) = 3
0 * 7 + (3 % 7) = 3
(3 % 7) = 3
```

This is defined in C99 §6.5.5, Multiplicative operators.

Answer (score 4):

- 7 divided by 3 is 2 with a remainder of 1
- 3 divided by 7 is 0 with a remainder of 3

Answer (score 3):

As long as they're both positive, the remainder will be equal to the dividend. If one or both is negative, then you get reminded that `%` is really the remainder operator, not the modulus operator. A modulus will always be positive, but a remainder can be negative.

Comment: A modulus can be negative. You can choose _any_ coset represenative.

Comment: Algebraically, the remainder is always positive. C is simply wrong in this regard, and it's an endless source of trouble. :-(

Comment: Regardless of you prefer to define your terms, `%` (as it's defined in C and C++) can produce a negative result, which many people don't expect.

Answer (score 1):

`(7 * 0) + 3 = 3`; therefore, the remainder is `3`.

Answer (score 1):

a % q = r means there is a x so that q * x + r = a.

So, 7 % 3 = 1 because 3 * 2 + 1 = 7,

and 3 % 7 = 3 because 7 * 0 + 3 = 3

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot to mention the surprising case, if the divident is smaller and negative:

```
-3 % 7 

result: 4
```

Comment: Never in C99 or later (which most people were using even in 2010 much less now), and only rarely before that (it was implementation-dependent, but most C implementations followed hardware and most hardware rounded quotient toward zero not toward -inf). https://stackoverflow.com/a/3622318/2868801 had this right 11 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

For my brain to understand this kind of question, I'm always converting it to a real world object, for example if I convert your question **3 % 7**. I'm going to represent the **"3"** as a **3-inch wide metal hole**, then the **"7"** as a 7 **inch metal screw**. Can you insert the **7 inch metal screw** to a **3 inch wide metal hole**? Of course not, therefore the answer should be the 3-inch metal hole, it doesn't matter even let say you have a **1000 or a million inch wide screw**, it is still 3, because how many times can you insert the 1000 or a million inch wide screw to a 3 inch wide metal hole? Zero times, right?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and effective catch to remember would be:
Whenever **dividend** is less than the **divisor**, modulus is just that **dividend**.

Let's formulate this:

```
if x < y, then x % y = x
```